# How to check if I have an active login session with Ruby and cron?

Tags: ruby, cron

I have a cron task that calls a Ruby script every minute. But I don't want the script to do anything, unless I'm logged in.

I found this snippet in the internet, to be placed in the beginning of the script:

```
exit unless `who -q`.include? ENV['USER']
```

The problem is that only works when I call the script myself. When it runs from cron, Postfix sends me this message:

```
`include?': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
```

Doesn't `who -q` return anything for a cron job? What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting question [Reasons why crontab does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) and it turns out cron doesn't have the `$USER` variable set up, but has a `$LOGNAME` variable that has the same value (at least in my environment).

So, either set up `$USER` in `crontab` or use `$LOGNAME`.